# (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I am getting this error when I am trying to load my .net 2.0 code in to one of our server.

```
The base class includes the field 'imageDescription', but its type 
(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor) is not compatible with the type of control 
(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl).
         ...         at   
System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateCodeDomTreeGenerator.BuildFieldDeclaration(
                                       ControlBuilderbuilder)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is conflict between two namespaces. Try to remove (or add):

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl;
```